# webview goes blank when loading url in android ics

Tags: android, webview

I am working in a application that has urls for loading in webview, every thing is working fine till andorid api level 13, but for andorid ics it behaves differently, some url loads properly but some causes screen flickering when loaded, I have not urls having https these are simple http urls. I can not understand why it is happening, please help me.
my code is-

```
                  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "",
                   "Loading...");
                  progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

                  webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                  webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClientICS());
                  webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                  PluginState state = WebSettings.PluginState.ON;
                  webview.getSettings().setPluginState(state);
                  webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                  webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
                  webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

                  webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                  public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                    if (view.getProgress() == 100) {
                         progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                   }
                  webview.loadUrl(url);

                   }

       private class MyWebViewClientICS extends WebViewClient {
       @Override
       public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.d("onReceivedError", errorCode + "" + description
                + "failingUrl" + failingUrl);
        Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,
                "Sorry, error in loading page, please try again",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().supportZoom();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks good to me. Have you tried using the standard "WebViewClient" instead of you own "MyWebViewClientICS" ?

Comment: previously, I am using it,but of no use, i know webview of andorid ics is buggy, but what i should do for resolving issue of flickering

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(WebPage.this, "", "Loading...");
url = getIntent().getStringExtra("website");
System.out.println("Url is " + url);
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);
        if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
web.loadUrl("http://"+url)
```

Comment: sorry, but it did'nt solve my problem, still fickering in andorid 4.03, please give more suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

old question. But this is what solved the problem for me.

```
 webView.setBackgroundColor(0x77000000);
```