# Extremly weird behaviour on WebViews when those are large in 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-webview

When I render a large Webview on android 4.1, the webview loads correctly, but also popsout of the layout. Here's an example:
[image]

As you can see in the top left corner, there's a white space, that shouldn't be there. If I tap with my finger it, it disappears...

I've tried to invalidate & requestLayout the top level container of this contentView, but it's still happening.

As I said in title, this is only happening in 4.0.4 devices (I know that 4.1 are ok.)

Do you guys know what else could I try?

Thanks.

**Edit**
That blank rectangle, is somehow over the menubar. Maybe invalidating menu will solve it?
I've tried: `this.invalidateOptionsMenu();` and still the same issue.

**Edit2:**
This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/containerTotaApp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<View
    android:id="@+id/rightshadow"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contentContainer"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_right" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bgImageSliderContainer"
    android:layout_width="700dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000000" >

</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerRightOptional"
        android:layout_width="680dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigationContainer"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#393939" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerTopMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/companybg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textEntradaMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="COMPANY"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/containerTopMenu">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerEntradesMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navigationContainer" 
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleContentContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:background="#EBEBEB">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:src="@drawable/vista2_cerca" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#288BA2"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separadortop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleContentContainer"
        android:background="#cecece"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separadortop"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separadortop2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:background="#cecece" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separadortop2"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/variableContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The webviews are added dynamically to `VariableContent`

Comment: Post your XML otherwise no one will be able to help you ...

Comment: @bluewhile. I've added it. I didn't add it because I didn't think you needed it, as maybe it was a known issue.

Comment: Is the result somewhat dependent from the content of the WebView? Have you tried isolating the webview in a bare test-application (which contains only the layout and the strict necessary to display the WebView)?

Comment: @Rick77 I don't understand the first question. About the second, no, I didnt try. The problem is that I cant move or change the layouts at all, because like 2k code lines are already using this layout as it is.

Comment: Sorry, I was just asking you if the problem manifest itself no matter what page you load with the WebView

Comment: Yea, the page content doesn't matter. Just it's lenght.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Granted that I can't pinpoint exactly what the source of your problem is, you can give disabling the hardware acceleration a try:

```
web.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

There are also other "interesting" options that you might try to switch on and off:

```
webv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

(I know that caching shouldn't be related to your problem, but turning caching off fixed the most curious glitches in my webview, so you probably want to try yourself) and

```
web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
```

No offense to the developers Team, but WebViews on Android are quite a mess, and here are a couple of links to back this statement up:

- [hardware accelerated webview slide-in animation flickering on ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132749/hardware-accelerated-webview-slide-in-animation-flickering-on-ics)
- [webview goes blank when loading url in android ics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595471/webview-goes-blank-when-loading-url-in-android-ics)
- [WebView, showing blank in ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155800/webview-showing-blank-in-ics)

which might also be useful to you.

Let us know if you find some solution anyway

Hope this helps